# How does google cloud messaging verify it's the correct app server?

Tags: android, security, google-cloud-messaging

When sending down stream messages from the app server to GCM to the client, how does GCM verify that it is actually from the app server and not some spoof? For example, I could use a REST client and send POST requests to GCM that would still reach the registered client as long as I have the API key and user ids. Is it all about making sure the API key does not get exposed then? Are expected to do some extra verifications on the Client?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict allowed server IP addresses at Google developers console.

Answer (score 0):

The API key is the main means of identifying an allowed sender. If you have the API key and the client InstanceId token (id) then you are an allowed sender, this is by design. You can revoke API keys if you believe that they have been compromised.